# Getting data from multiple tables using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have various tables like

```
Student
primary id , students name, course

Papers
paper id, papername, course, semester, type

StudentOptions
primary id, studentid (foreign key - reference student id) and paperid (foreign key - references paper id)

StudentsTerm
studentid (foreign key- references student id) and student semester
```

Now the kind of result i want is,

I want to choose a course then the term, which will give me the number of papers/subject it has with their types (Mandatory/Optional) and with that i want to have the count of number of students studying those papers from all these tables.

I don't wanna create any view or stuff, Just a normal select query will do.

The query i am running is :

```
SELECT p_name,
       p_id,
       type,
       Count(sps.studentid) AS counts
FROM   students,
       str,
       papers
       LEFT JOIN sps
              ON sps.paperid = papers.p_id
WHERE  sps.studentid = students.studentid
       AND students.studentid = str.studentid
       AND sps.studentid = str.studentid
       AND str.semesterid = p_semid
       AND str.sessionid = 12
       AND students.course = c_id
       AND c_id = 6
       AND p_semid = 1
GROUP  BY p_id
```

Comment: What is your current query returning? What's not working?

Comment: It is giving me only those papers in which student are studying. I want all the papers for that given semester and course and if there aren't any studying then it should give me zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As better practice, if you are going to be using explicit `JOIN` syntax, then don't use implicit syntax. In the query you posted above, you select from `papers`, but you don't use it anywhere. Also, your column names are slightly ambiguous. If it's easier, alias each table using a single letter, or explicitly prefix the column names. If you're using an aggregate with `GROUP BY`, you cannot select columns which are not in the group.

Let's assume this is your ER diagram:

[image]

Let's first join all the tables:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM student a
JOIN str b ON b.student_id = a.id
JOIN sps c ON c.student_id = a.id
JOIN papers d ON d.id = c.paper_id
```

Now you wish to find the number of students studying papers from a specific course and type:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM student a
JOIN str b ON b.student_id = a.id
JOIN sps c ON c.student_id = a.id
JOIN papers d ON d.id = c.paper_id
WHERE b.semester = 12
    AND d.course = 6
```

Because your attributes are ambigiuous, it is hard to tell what tables they are coming from. If you can set up the structure and sample data on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com), we could help you better.

Comment: I want to have papers name from papers, this is why am using it.

Comment: @IPerfect [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a910b/1) is a query that join's all the tables. Do you want to try filtering your result?

Comment: This is what i dont want . I want all the papers from papers table depending on the course and the number of student currently studying it.

Comment: check this out. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a910b/6 . this is the kind of result i want but i want to add in studentterm and studentcourse table as well.

Comment: this is not the result i want. I also want maths II with 0 students be shown in the result.

Comment: @IPerfect Then you want a `LEFT JOIN`. See [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/777c6d/2).